"expected string" result when publishing an event to pusher using curl
I am trying to publish an event to Pusher, using curl from a bash script. I have the following function:
function publishEvent() {
  declare    cluster="us2"
  declare    appID="XXXXXXX"
  declare    appKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  declare    appSecret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  declare    channel="servers"
  declare    event=${1}
  declare    server=${2}
  declare    data='{"data":"{\"message\":\"'${server}'\"}","name":"'${event}'","channel":"'${channel}'"}'
  declare    timestamp=$(date +%s)

  declare    url="https://api-${cluster}.pusher.com/apps/${appID}/events"
  declare    params=""
  declare    md5=$(echo -n ${data} | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
  params+="auth_key=${appKey}"
  params+="&auth_timestamp=${timestamp}"
  params+="&auth_version=1.0"
  params+="&body_md5=${md5}"

  declare    signature=$(printf "POST\n/apps/${appID}/events\n${params}" |
    openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac ${appSecret} | cut -d' ' -f2)

  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -H "Authorization: Pusher ${appKey}:${signature}" \
       -H "X-Pusher-Auth-Version: 1.0" \
       -H "X-Pusher-Auth-Timestamp: ${timestamp}" \
       -d "${data}" --http1.1 \
       "${url}?${params}"
}

When I run the function, I get the result "expected string", with no other information.
For completeness, the actual curl command is:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Pusher {KEY}:{SIG}' -H 'X-Pusher-Auth-Version: 1.0' -H 'X-Pusher-Auth-Timestamp: 1716234427' -d '{"data":"{\"message\":\"\"}","name":"start","channel":"servers"}' --http1.1 'https://api-us2.pusher.com/apps/{ID}/events?auth_key={KEY}&auth_timestamp=1716234427&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=9916bc8c99314c57fefc8cddb8d64a66
I have replaced the actual AppID, AppKey, and Signature with {ID}. {KEY}, and {SIG} respecively.
